# Reverse words of a char[]/sentence in place

Tags: java, string, reverse

I want to reverse the words of a string in place using constant space. The catch is that the words cannot contain consecutive whitespaces. I want to reduce all consecutive whitespaces between words to one whitespace and also ignore leading and trailing whitespaces. I was able to implement the in place reversal of words, but I'm struggling to implement removing the consecutive whitespaces between words and leading and trailing whitespaces. Can someone help me?

Here is what I have so far:

```
public char[] reverseWords(char[] s) {

    if (s == null)
        return null;

    int right = 0;


    s = reverseString(s, 0, s.length - 1);// get the reversed sentence
    //System.out.println(s);
    for (int left = 0; left < s.length; left++) {

        if (s[left] != ' ') {// for first word

            for (right = left; right < s.length && s[right] != ' '; right++)
                ; // get end of word

            s = reverseString(s, left, right - 1);
            left =(right - 1);// move left index to end of
                                                // word

            // s[left++] = ' ';
        }

    }
    return s;
}

public char[] reverseString(char[] strChars, int start, int end) {

    if (strChars == null)
        return null;

    while (start < end) {

        char temp = strChars[start];
        strChars[start] = strChars[end];
        strChars[end] = temp;

        start++;
        end--;
    }
    return strChars;
}
```

Comment: Yes, how would you do that with a character array of the entire sentence?

Comment: Right. I thought your question said "String". My bad.

Comment: Could you do a `.replace(" ","")`?

Comment: @Aarowaim `char`s don't have methods...

Comment: @NicolásCarlo Ah, sorry. I don't see why char[] is being used instead of String, but you are correct.

Comment: Yes, but we need constant space solution, using another char array would make it O(n) space solution right?

Comment: after you removed the consecutive spaces, what would you want to fill the extra character at the end with?

Comment: From the lefthand side, find the first non-whitespace character and do the same from the right hand side. Now before swapping the number first check about the next char whether it's whitespace or not and adjust the array and length according to that.

Comment: i think, if you have to use constant space, you can't make it better than O(n^2). Because, if you want to remove a whitespace between words, you have to move each char from the rest of your char-array one position to the left...

Comment: `left = left + (right - left - 1)`, simple arithmetic tell me that you can simplify it to `left = right -1 `

Comment: I'm not sure why this question has been downvoted and I would really like to  know the reason for it. I think that this is a good exercise in computer science. If I can understand the reason for the downvote, I would make sure that I don't make the same mistake in my next post.

Comment: @Adrian Right, Updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is going to be easier/faster ways.  I am just giving a thought which should be good in learning purpose.

First, do whatever you have now, which reverse words, and leave those consecutive space untouched.

then write another method to do consecutive space removing.

have 2 pointer, start at the first position where it is not space.

A and B keep on moving on together.

if (A != B), then we do `s[A] = s[B]; s[B] = ' ';`

If `s[A]` and `s[A-1]` is space, then A stop (A is now at the 2nd space), and only B continue moving forward.  By such way, A stay the same position and will continue to copy from B, until B gives a non-space character.

and it ends when B hit the end.

in psuedo code, it is something like

```
int a = first position of non-space;
int b = a;

while b < s.size() {
  if (a != b) {
    s[a] = s[b]
    s[b] = ' '
  }
  if (both s[a] and s[a-1] are space)  { 
    increment b;
    // leave a untouched
  } else {
    increment a;
    increment b;
  }
}
```

Constant space, O(n) time

---

Another way, which can handle the removal of consecutive space in place when reversing words:

The hint is, include those extra spaces when doing reverse.

e.g. Given a string

```
abc    def     ghi
L                 (left)
```

first reverse is trivial so I am skipping it.  The hint is, for second word, you are going to stop the L at the position right after the first space:

```
cba    def     ghi
    L
```

the "right" side of the reverse is going to be the first right boundary of word:

```
cba    def     ghi
    L    R
```

Then do the reverse in place

```
cba fed        ghi
    L    R
```

Then keep on finding the next position of L to start reverse again:

```
cba fed        ghi
        L
```

Take similar logic

```
cba fed        ghi
        L        R
```

then

```
cba fed ihg       
        L        R
```

Answer (score 1):

A very, very simple one-line solution would be to use [REGEX (short for REGular EXpression)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). I have two ways of doing this and I'm using the [`String#replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and [`String#trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) method for this. So, here goes:

```
String line = "    Hello     World!  ";
line = line.replaceAll(" +", " "); // '+' = 1 or more i.e. at least 1.
// Hence it replaces ALL white spaces with a single space.
line = line.trim(); //This 'trims' the String to remove all leading and trailing 
// whitespaces.
System.out.println(line); //Output: "Hello World!"
```

A more accepted practice is to use `"\\s+"` instead of `" "`. (Actually the character is `\s` but double slashes should be used when storing in a `String`.) You'll still get the same result. You could also try using the [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)-[`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) approach.